kivymd :MDTopAppBar Raise MDTopAppBarTitle error
class AppBarScreen(MDScreen):
def init(self, **kwargs):
super(AppBarScreen, self).init(**kwargs)
    # create a appbar
    app_bar=MDTopAppBar(
        # left icon
        MDTopAppBarLeadingButtonContainer(
            MDActionTopAppBarButton(icon='menu'),
        ),
        # center title
        MDTopAppBarTitle(
            text='hello',
            pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5},
        ),
        # end
        MDTopAppBarTrailingButtonContainer(
            MDActionTopAppBarButton(icon='account-circle-outline'),
            MDActionTopAppBarButton(icon='access-point'),
            MDActionTopAppBarButton(icon='dots-vertical'),
        ),
    )

    app_bar.size_hint=(1, 0.05)
    app_bar.pos_hint={
        "x": 0, "y": 0.95
    }
    app_bar.type='small'

    relative_layout=MDRelativeLayout()

    relative_layout.add_widget(app_bar)
    self.add_widget(relative_layout)

22:<MDTopAppBarTitle>
23:    padding:


24:        [
25:        self._appbar._left_padding,
26:        0,
...
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_left_padding'



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
